# Why is Rails ActionCable available without mounting

Tags: ruby-on-rails, websocket, ruby-on-rails-6, actioncable

I would like to use action cable in my rails 6 application with the ruby_graphql gem.
I have noticed that when I simply add

`require "action_cable/engine"` to my application.rb
and the required code for `Connection < ActionCable::Connection::Base`, `Channel < ActionCable::Channel::Base` etc

the websocket becomes available under `/cable` even though I have NOT added
`mount ActionCable.server => '/cable'`

I don't understand why the `/cable` route would become available without mounting it in the routes file. I have also noticed that my application's resource consumption (in particular CPU) goes up with the simple `require "action_cable/engine". I would have expected that to only happen once I mounted it

Any help and insight into this would be greatly appreciated

(I made sure to restart all my servers between changes and check the generated routes to see that /cable was not included - I then tested the websocket using new WebSocket('wss://my-domain.test/cable') both in develop & production which both times successfully upgraded to a websocket with a 101 status code)

Answer (score 2):

Take a look into the file you are `require`-ing: [action_cable/engine](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/main/actioncable/lib/action_cable/engine.rb)

More specifically the following section of code

```rb
    initializer "action_cable.routes" do
      config.after_initialize do |app|
        config = app.config
        unless config.action_cable.mount_path.nil?
          app.routes.prepend do
            mount ActionCable.server => config.action_cable.mount_path, internal: true, anchor: true
          end
        end
      end
    end
```

Just the action of requiring the engine creates an initializer that adds the route to the top of your application routes.

A few lines later it also starts the server

```rb
      ActiveSupport.on_load(:action_cable) do
        app.reloader.before_class_unload do
          ActionCable.server.restart
        end
      end
```

This is why the route is there and action_cable seems to just work out of the box even without explicitly starting anything. It just happens inside `require "action_cable/engine"`

Comment: Thank you! That makes perfect sense. Do you know if there is straight forward way (such as some config option) to conditionally mount it when requiring this file? Presumably I would have to monkey patch it?
Potentially I could set `mount_path = nil`?


Or is it possible to require a different file in application.rb (such as just `require "action_cable"`) and then just have the routes file mount?

Comment: `require "action_cable"` should work. Look through the `engine.rb` and add what you need into your own codebase if it doesn't just work out of the box.